# Sorting ArrayList based on number of duplicates?

Tags: java, loops

working here to sort an ArrayList in order with the highest number of duplicates at index 0. Can anyone help me out with what kind of loop to use or a method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Please think about accepting an answer or vote up, this is how a forum works, newcomers will more easily go to see accepted post rather than non-accepted

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Collections#frequency`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object)) to get the occurrences, and map the the object accordingly. This way if the same object is encountered multiple times, it wont be stored more than once:

```
    // Map to store in
    HashMap<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
    // Iterate
    for (Object obj : list) {
        // Map according to occurrences
        map.put(Collections.frequency(list, obj), obj);
    }
```

If you want to access the contents in **ascending** order, you can stream the key set and sort it:

```
map.keySet().stream().sorted().forEach(k -> System.out.println(map.get(k) + ":" + k));
```

If you want  to access the contends in **descending** order, you can use make a comparator that is opposite of [`Integer#compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)):

```
map.keySet().stream().sorted((k1, k2) ->  (k1 < k2) ? 1 : ((k1 == k2) ? 0 : -1)).forEach(k -> System.out.println(map.get(k) + ":" + k));
```

If you do not wish to stream your key set (say you are accessing at different lines), you can use an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) instead:

```
Iterator<Integer> descending = map.keySet().stream().sorted((k1, k2) ->  (k1 < k2) ? 1 : ((k1 == k2) ? 0 : -1)).iterator();
Iterator<Integer> ascending = map.keySet().stream().sorted().iterator();

while(descending.hasNext()) {
    int i = descending.next();
    System.out.println(map.get(i) + ":" + i);
}
while(ascending.hasNext()) {
    int i = ascending.next();
    System.out.println(map.get(i) + ":" + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by steps :

- compute the frequency of each element
- for each element compare using their frequency (map)

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9);
Map<Integer, Long> couterMap = list.stream().collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(list);
list.sort(Comparator.comparingLong(couterMap::get));
// details : list.sort((o, p) -> Long.compare(couterMap.get(o), couterMap.get(p)));
System.out.println(list);
```

You get

```
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9]
```

The ones that appear only once (`1,2,3`) then the ones that appear twice (`4,5,6`), ant then the ones that appear 3 times (`7,8,9`)

---

To obtain `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9]`

use : `list.sort(Comparator.comparingLong(couterMap::get).thenComparingInt(Integer.class::cast));`